# how to pass tag on button action

Tags: ios, objective-c

in my form I need to pass a tag to the button action

```
[acceptbuttontextedit addTarget:self action:@selector(mytag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

here `mytag` is the tag which I want to sent for button action and

```
- (IBAction)mytag:(id)sender
{

}
```

I need to get that tag in my action.

I am new in objective-c so if anyone could help me in this issue it would be a great help .

Comment: `mytag` is a method here, not a tag

Comment: @Andrey Gordeev then how could I pass a tag to the action. Could you send me the code ?

Comment: Tag means what you actually you meaning ? can you tell an example ? Could you make it little more clear ? In objective c tag means an integer assigned to UI component

Comment: you can use sender.tag for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the button tag before you are going to add target. like

```
acceptbuttontextedit.tag=1;
[acceptbuttontextedit addTarget:self action:@selector(mytag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then access the tag through sender:

```
- (IBAction)mytag:(UIButton *)sender
{
   NSInteger buttonTag = sender.tag;
}
```

Where, `acceptbuttontextedit` is your `UIButton`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
[acceptbuttontextedit addTarget:self action:@selector(mytag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
acceptbuttontextedit.tag=1;//set tag whatever

- (IBAction)mytag:(UIButton *)sender
{
   int buttonIndex=sender.tag;
    if (buttonIndex==1) {
    //do your stuff here
   }
}
```

May it will help.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that you have to add **tag** of your **button**, such like `acceptbuttontextedit.tag = 101;`  Then Change your action method to

```
- (IBAction)mytag:(UIButton *)sender
```

And you can get it by

```
- (IBAction)mytag:(UIButton *)sender
{
   NSLog(@"%d", sender.tag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is very simple. Set the tag to your button.

```
acceptbuttontextedit.tag = 1;
[acceptbuttontextedit addTarget:self action:@selector(mytag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now simply access the tag through sender:

```
- (IBAction)mytag: (id) responder
{
   int buttonTag  = (UIButton *) responder.tag;
   // Do the specific things with your tag now
}
```